# Automatic Summarization only returns first sentence - Python / Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, flask, nltk

Trying to create a site that uses multiple algorithms to auto summarize articles. Running into an issue where only the first sentence is taken from the selection, any help is appreciated.

I am using the library sumy which is a summarization library and using flask and HTML/CSS to output the automated summarizations from the algorithm. Other than LSA, the only output that comes out is the first sentence, leading me to believe it's something to do with my "para" variable. I created it because it appends strings to create full paragraphs, but I'm sure there's an easier way to do it.

```
   @app.route('/dependent', methods = ['POST'])
def mySumD():
if request.form['action'] == 'LSA':
    para = ""
    url = request.form['url_link']
    parser = HtmlParser.from_url(url, Tokenizer(LANGUAGE))
    stemmer = Stemmer(LANGUAGE)
    summarizer = Summarizer(stemmer)
    summarizer.stop_words = get_stop_words(LANGUAGE)

    for sentence in summarizer(parser.document, SENTENCES_COUNT):
        data = str(sentence)
        para += data 
    return render_template('dependent.html', para = para)

elif request.form['action'] == 'Luhn':
    para = ""
    url = request.form['url_link']
    parser = HtmlParser.from_url(url, Tokenizer(LANGUAGE))
    stemmer = Stemmer(LANGUAGE)
    summarizer = LuhnSummarizer(stemmer)
    summarizer.stop_words = get_stop_words(LANGUAGE)

    for sentence in summarizer(parser.document, SENTENCES_COUNT):
        data = str(sentence)
        para += data 
        return render_template('dependent.html', para = para)

elif request.form['action'] == 'LexRank':
    para = ""
    url = request.form['url_link']
    parser = HtmlParser.from_url(url, Tokenizer(LANGUAGE))
    stemmer = Stemmer(LANGUAGE)
    summarizer = LexSummarizer(stemmer)
    summarizer.stop_words = get_stop_words(LANGUAGE)

    for sentence in summarizer(parser.document, SENTENCES_COUNT):
        data = str(sentence)
        para += data 
        return render_template('dependent.html', para = para)
```

---

```
<form action = "{{ url_for('mySumD') }}" method = "POST" id="urlForm" class="standard">

 <input type="url" id = "url" name="url_link" class= "form-control" placeholder="Insert URL here...">
        <div id="url_field_is_empty" class="error" style="display: none"> You must submit a valid URL</div>
  <h1>Choose Your Summarization Method</h1>
  <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%" id="subscribersoptions">
     <button style="width:20%" type ="submit" name="action" value="LSA">LSA</button>
     <button style="width:20%" type ="submit" name="action" value="Luhn">Luhn</button>
     <button style="width:20%" type ="submit" name="action" value="LexRank">Lex Rank</button>
     <button style="width:20%" type ="submit" name="action" value="TextRank">Text Rank</button>
     <button style="width:20%" type ="submit" name="action" value="SumBasic">SumBasic</button>
     <button style="width:20%" type ="submit" name="action" value="KL-Sum">KL-Sum</button>
  </div>    
  <br>
  {{para}}

</form>
```